# VBA Next Loop Not Working

Tags: excel, vba, loops

This is the first time i have used VBA. I have successfully created a loop that completes what i want it too. 

However when it loops to the second worksheet the "for" doesn't  appear to work. I need this to be "reset".

Please see the code below, i hope you can see why its not working:

```
For Each ws In wStock.Sheets
 ws.Activate
 i = 0
   For i = 1 To 4


    FullName = ActiveSheet.Cells(37, ii).Value
    Name = Split(FullName, " ")

    For intCount = LBound(Name) To UBound(Name)
      sData.Range("C" & iii).Value = Name(0)
      sData.Range("D" & iii).Value = Name(1)
    Next

    ActiveSheet.Cells(38, ii).Copy
    sData.Range("F" & iii).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

  Address = ActiveSheet.Cells(39, ii).Value
  Address1 = Split(Address, ",")

     For intCount = LBound(Address1) To UBound(Address1)
        sData.Range("H" & iii).Value = Address1(0)
        sData.Range("J" & iii).Value = Address1(1)
     Next

    ActiveSheet.Cells(24, ii).Copy
    sData.Range("Y" & iii).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ActiveSheet.Cells(18, ii).Copy
    sData.Range("Z" & iii).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ActiveSheet.Cells(20, ii).Copy
    sData.Range("AA" & iii).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ActiveSheet.Cells(22, ii).Copy
    sData.Range("AB" & iii).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ActiveSheet.Cells(33, ii).Copy
    sData.Range("AC" & iii).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ii = ii + 1
    iii = iii + 1

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

   Next i
Next ws
```

I look forward to hearing from someone soon :)

Comment: Where do you initialize `ii` and `iii`? Also just a tip - I'd strongly recommend, for the sake of readability, using something instead of those variables... typically people here would use `i`, `j` and `k` instead of `i`, `ii` and `iii`.

Comment: What's `i` used for anyway? Also you're not resetting `ii` or `iii` anywhere in the outer loop. I'd recommend you pull the inner loop body into its own procedure, so that the counters are properly scoped and don't need to be reset.

Comment: ii and iii are declared out of the loop to state what row and column to start at. This is the first VBA script I have completed so it may not be the best. I am just wondering why the first loop it pastes the values where I want them and the second, third, forth etc time it doesn’t. i on its own is to count the number of columns I think. I am using this to go through a spreadsheet for 1600 items and put them in a different format. Thanks for your replies so far.

Comment: I _think_ that's your problem: you are not reinitializing `ii` and `iii` when you loop through to the next `ws`

Comment: Try putting a break point where you increment `ii = ii + 1` and see what you get in the Immediate Window. What is the value before executing the line, and after. You can set a break point by going to the line and pressing F9. Report back your results.

Comment: I aree with all comments above. If you want to be sure the loop is running put this line rigth under the `For i...`: `Debug.Print "running on sheet " & ws.Name & ", loop: " & i`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I managed to complete it now with the suggestion from cybernetic.nomad. I needed to reinitialise the ii and iii in the foreach loop :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help! I managed to complete it now with the suggestion from cybernetic.nomad. I needed to reinitialise the ii and iii in the foreach loop :)

```
For Each ws In wStock.Sheets
  ws.Activate
  i = 0
  ii = 2
  iii = iii
  For i = 1 To 4
    FullName = ActiveSheet.Cells(37, ii).Value
    Name = Split(FullName, " ")

    For intCount = LBound(Name) To UBound(Name)
      sData.Range("C" & iii).Value = Name(0)
      sData.Range("D" & iii).Value = Name(1)
    Next

    ActiveSheet.Cells(38, ii).Copy
    sData.Range("F" & iii).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Address = ActiveSheet.Cells(39, ii).Value
    Address1 = Split(Address, ",")

    For intCount = LBound(Address1) To UBound(Address1)
      sData.Range("H" & iii).Value = Address1(0)
      sData.Range("J" & iii).Value = Address1(1)
    Next

    ActiveSheet.Cells(24, ii).Copy
    sData.Range("Y" & iii).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ActiveSheet.Cells(18, ii).Copy
    sData.Range("Z" & iii).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ActiveSheet.Cells(20, ii).Copy
    sData.Range("AA" & iii).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ActiveSheet.Cells(22, ii).Copy
    sData.Range("AB" & iii).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ActiveSheet.Cells(33, ii).Copy
    sData.Range("AC" & iii).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ii = ii + 1
    iii = iii + 1

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

  Next i
Next ws
```